# Not found message in django 1.9.1 [temporary closed]

Tags: django

I updated yesterday from django 1.8.6 to 1.9.1 and my project went smoothly. But as I was coding, I noticed a message in the command prompt. It says

```
Not Found: /ticket/222
[05/Jan/2016 10:29:05] "GET /ticket/222 HTTP/1.1" 301 0
[05/Jan/2016 10:29:05] "GET /ticket/222/ HTTP/1.1" 200 9972
```

Sometimes it appears like this. But I swear, it is there.

```
Not Found: /favicon.ico
[12/Jan/2016 10:32:09] "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1" 404 3254
```

222 is the id and the weird thing is, I am looking at 222's details on my page. Any explanations for this? Or is this a bug? Should I be bothered by this?

---

EDIT
Seems like no one can give me answers. So I'll have this closed but if anyone have a clue on this, just comment down below.

Comment: If it's an exception you need to post the full stacktrace of the error. If it's not an exception, you need to find the code that prints it.

Comment: @ShangWang please see my edit. And it's not an error. It's a sort of a message that just pops out randomly. It is not consistent as to when it will appear

Comment: That shouldn't be a message that randomly pops up, either your code is using `print` to print it, or some 3rd party package is printing that. Do a `grep -r "Not Found"  .` in the root of your code base and see if there's anything come up.

Comment: @ShangWang I am using Windows. How can I do it in windows? And I am sure that it is not me printing it

Comment: try to migrate again

Comment: It seems like no one knew the answer. Anyway thank you.